# Index in a CM field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Fix a prime number $p$ and set $q=p^r$. Let be $P(X)$ a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ of the form

$P(X)=X^4+aX^3+bX^2+aqX+q^2$

where

$|a|\leq 4\sqrt{q}$ and $2|a|\sqrt{q} - 2q \leq b \leq \frac{a^4}{4}+2q$

This is a Weil polynomial. Let $\alpha$ be one of its roots and set $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$

It is possible to know the index $(\mathcal{O}_K: \mathbb{Z}[\alpha,q/\alpha])$?

It is possible to have a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,q/\alpha]$? Or in general, for a polynomial $P$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ of degree $\leq 3$, a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[P(\alpha),\alpha,q/\alpha]$?